# Adding items to a navigation toolbar

Tags: iphone

I have a navigation toolbar in which I am adding toolbar items programatically, as below.  The toolbar displays properly, and the toolbar style is set to black opaque. but the button on the toolbar does not display.  Why?

```
    //Set up the toolbar
 [[[self navigationController] toolbar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque]; 
 UIBarButtonItem *myButtonItem = 
 [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(handleMyButton)];
 NSArray *myItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: myButtonItem,nil];
 [[self navigationController] setToolbarItems:myItems animated:NO];
 [myButtonItem release];
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`UINavigationController` fetches the buttons that should be used for the navigation bar and the tool bar from the current visible view controller. This means that you add the buttons you want to have to the view controller, not the navigation controller. So it should work just fine if you do:

```
[self setToolbarItems:myItems animated:NO];
```

Compare that with how the add button is added to the navigation bar in the default template for a Navigation Based Application with Core Data:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

This means that when you push a new view controller the buttons in the tool bar will disappear and then appear again when you pop back.

Comment: Robert - Thanks.  That not only solves the issue, but helps me understand what's going on.

Comment: Robert, great answer! I have to agree with Don Wilson! Thanks

Comment: thanks a lot for `[self setToolbarItems:myItems animated:NO];`

Answer (score 0):

To assign buttons to the toolbar you would call this method

```
[toolbar setItems:];
```

Instead of

```
[[self navigationController] setToolbarItems: animated:];
```

Comment: Tried this, with same result.  See comments above.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the toolbar owned by your navigationController in the first line and not in the 4th line.  It would appear that the necessary fix is:

```
[[[self navigationController] toolbar] setToolbarItems:myItems animated:NO];
```

instead of your current line 4.

Comment: UIToolbar does not have a setToolbarItems method. It does have a setItems method, as described in the answer below.  However, if I use that approach, I get the same result.  UINavigationController has a setToolbarItems method whose purpose is to set items on the default toolbar, correct?  I'm still not seeing why the code above has a problem.

Comment: This line is more coorect        [[[self navigationController] toolbar] setItems:items animated:NO];

Answer (score 0):

Show the toolbar by setting the toolbarHidden property of the navigation controller object to NO.