# How to set toolbar userInteractionEnabled = NO?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, toolbar, user-interaction

I was using method in below to show a toolbar on bottom with a title.

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title"
                                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                        target:nil
                                                        action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                        target:nil
                                                                        action:nil];

NSArray *items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:spacer, item, spacer, nil];
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

However, the title on toolbar is **clickable**, and I've no idea to **disable user interaction** from it because the toolbar was created by self navigationController.

Do you guys have resolution for this? 
Thanks for your prompt helped in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem perfect solved by:

```
[[[self navigationController] toolbar] setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

and I found out there've more details to custom toolbar in navigation. [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297737/adding-items-to-a-navigation-toolbar)